# Fuser returns empty list for opened file

Tags: linux, files, fuser

Why when I do:

```
$ kate file.txt &
```

and

```
$ fuser file.txt
```

I've got empty list. After all, kate process opens file.txt

Comment: Depends on how kate manages its files. A better test would be to run tail -f file.txt and then fuser file.txt while tail is running. Also what does lsof file.txt say?

Answer (score 0):

It means that when you run `fuser file.txt`, process `kate` has already finished accessing the file.

Adapted from the manpage: `fuser` displays  the  PIDs of processes *currently* using the specified files or file systems.